# Android activity lifecycle state across different activities × 99416

Tags: android

I have four activities A,B,C and D.
I am moving from Activity A---->B--->C--->D

And from activity D i am calling activity B.

By the time i reach to activity D from A-B-C-D

The states of Activity A,B and C is onStop() state and activity D is onResume() state.
There are two scenarios ahead:
1>I press the back button and go to activity C or
2>I invoke an event and go to Activity B.

First scenario is understood wrt activity states.
D-Destroy state and C will be onrestart-onstart-onresume

### Second Scenario

Activity D goes to OnStop and for Activity B-->Oncreate-Onstart-OnResume...
and Activity A and C will be on onStop() state...

I wanted to know as the state of the Activity B before the event was onStop(),
but inspite of calling the onRestart() method it has called the onCreate-onStart-onResume.

As, the Activity B was not destroyed than where did the Activity B which was originally on 
onStop() state go ........And from this activity B when i move to Activity C ...it calls the onCreate-onStart-onResume for Activity C....for Activity C also the one which was onStop state has not been destroyed ......got confused with the life cycle and activity stack flow....Help me on the same...

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instances of the activity that's why you are seeing the flow `onCreate-onStart-onResume`. you need to add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to your activity before starting from the stack.